# Camshaft problem not sure what needs replacing

Tags: car, peugeot, valve, camshaft

I'm Looking for a part name and info on what could have caused the problem.

So I have an 03 peugoet 206 1.4 HDI and I lost a cylinder after going though them by disconnecting each injector and can see the 3rd from the left is not working. So I have striped the rocker cover off and can see that there is a little thing that goes to the top of the valves (in between the camshaft and valves) has snapped in half what is this part called?

If the camshaft has manged to snap this part what could have caused it? could the valve have seized to cause this? I have had a new cam belt quite recently could the be caused by it skipping a tooth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is the part you are looking for:

[image]

If so, it's called a [rocker arm](https://www.rexbo.eu/febi/rocker-arm-valve-train-36422?c=100398&at=33566). The most probable reason for its demise is metal fatigue or maybe it just broke.

Looking at [this forum](http://www.honestjohn.co.uk/forum/post/index.htm?t=79931) (and others), it appears that these were designed to fail in case of catastrophic cam belt failure. With that in mind, it's not inconceivable that one of them has broken just out of usage. You can readily buy replacement rockers to fix this issue. You probably want to inspect all of the rocker arms very closely to ensure others aren't ready to fail as well. A cautious person with money to burn might also want to replace all of the rockers just to ensure they are all on an even footing (as far as usage goes).

Comment: That looks right if I'm taking the cam case off I will replace at of them :) is there any way to test valve?

Comment: According to what I've read, your valve shouldn't have any issues ... beyond normal wear, that is. You can do cylinder compression and leak down tests to see if they are sealing correctly. You can look at the end of the valve stem to ensure there's nothing bad going on there. Ensure it is flat, not marred, and looking like the rest of them.

Answer (score 2):

Without a photo I would take a guess at it being a rocker arm.  It could have snapped due to age related stresses, or as you said you may have a valve problem.  A sticking valve could be caused by a lack of coolant in the head or maybe a lack of lubricant.